# LINQ Query - How i can make my query better?

Tags: linq

I have written following **LINQ** query to return list and then iterating list separately to convert time into hours and taking sum of hours for each list item.

I am sure this might not be the right away as it send three database calls.

**Can i re-write it in a better way e.g. GroupBy or by some other way to assign data to model, converting IdleTime into hours and than taking sum of IdleTime??**

**Model Class**

```
public class TestModel
{
    public string TaskSummary { get; set; }
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
    public float IdleTime { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public float IdleTimeSum { get; set; }
    public Guid TaskId { get; set; }
}
```

**LINQ Query**

```
List<TestModel> list = _context.Time
                             .Include(x => x.Report)
                             .Include(x => x.Report.Task)
                             .Include(x => x.Report.Task.Location)
                             .Where(x => taskIds.Contains(x.Report.TaskId))
                             .Select(x => new TestModel
                             {
                                 TaskSummary = x.Report.Task.Summary,
                                 LocationName = x.Report.Task.Location.Name,
                                 IdleTime = x.Duration,
                                 Description = x.Description,
                                 TaskId = x.Report.TaskId,
                             }).ToList();
```

**How i am converting into hours?**

```
foreach (var item in list)
    item.IdleTime = item. IdleTime / 60;
```

**How I am taking sum?**

```
        foreach (var item in list)
            item.IdleTimeSum = item. IdleTime;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add those to your projection:

```
                         .Select(x => new TestModel
                         {
                             TaskSummary = x.Report.Task.Summary,
                             LocationName = x.Report.Task.Location.Name,
                             IdleTime = x.Duration / 60.0f,
                             Description = x.Description,
                             TaskId = x.Report.TaskId,
                             NPTHoursSum = x.Duration / 60.0f,
                         }).ToList();
```

Although since you're not showing where you actually *sum* anything I suspect there's more to the problem than that.

Comment: Using IdleTime = x.Duration / 60 always gives 0 rather than expected value. Thats why i am iterating separately.

Comment: Is `IdleTime` an integer in the database?  Try `IdleTime / 60.0f` to force floating-point division.

Comment: Duration is of type int in the database. I got your point and i believe that the only reason IdleTime was getting 0. Thanks D Stanely.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah `Select` is a projection function, you can just do those operations in your select.

```
.Select(x => new TestModel
                             {
                                 TaskSummary = x.Report.Task.Summary,
                                 LocationName = x.Report.Task.Location.Name,
                                 IdleTime = x.Duration /60.0f,
                                 NPTHoursSum = x.Duration / 60.0f,
                                 Description = x.Description,
                                 TaskId = x.Report.TaskId,
                             }).ToList();
```

If you're using LINQ to SQL then the division operation will probably occur at the db. If you actually want to do a sum it would have to be in a different query or as a sub query or something.\

Comment: Using IdleTime = x.Duration / 60 always gives 0 rather than expected value. Thats why i am iterating separately.

Comment: @user1874957 what is the SQL type of Duration? The only reason I see it giving 0 is if it's an int with a value between 0 and 59.

Comment: Duration is of type int in the database. I got your point and i believe that the only reason IdleTime was getting 0. Thanks  evanmcdonnal